# A proxy command for deprecation

Tags: macros, expansion

I'm interested in defining a macro to deprecate other macros.  The system on which we are working goes through a lot of refactorings and is used by more than a couple people, so we want to be able to mark a command as deprecated before it is removed from the macros file entirely.  Specifically, I'd like to generalize

```
\let\fooDeprecated\foo
\renewcommand{\foo}{\warn{Deprecated command used}\fooDeprecated}
```

or, for that matter, anything else that will work as a simple LaTeX proxy macro (in the design pattern sense of the word "proxy").  Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out where to stick the `\expandafter` magic to make this work.  That is,

```
\newcommand{\deprecate}[1]{%
    \let\csname #1Deprecated\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname%
    \renewcommand{\csname #1\endcsname}{\warn{Deprecated command used}\csname #1Deprecated\endcsname}%
}
```

clearly doesn't work.  Is there a better way to do this?  If not, how do I figure out how to expand these things?

Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  :)  I didn't realize that this functionality was already provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package `amsmath` does something like you want for the primitive `\over` and its siblings.

Define two helper commands:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\deprecate}[2]{%
  % #1 is the deprecated command
  % #2 is the new command to use
  % Issue a message at first usage
  \PackageWarning{zach}{%
    Deprecated command \@backslashchar#1;\MessageBreak
    \protect#2\space should be used instead\MessageBreak
  }
  % globally redefine "\#1" to "\deprecate@#1"
  \global\expandafter\let\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname
                         \csname deprecated@#1\endcsname
  % issue the old command
  \csname#1\endcsname
}

\newcommand{\@deprecate}[2]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname deprecated@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname#1\endcsname
  \@namedef{#1}{\deprecate{#1}{#2}}%
}
```

Then you can give a list of the deprecated commands along with the new ones:

```
\@deprecate{foo}{\newfoo}
```

(notice that the deprecated command should be used "by name" in the first argument).

In the document, the first usage of `\foo` will type on the terminal and in the log file

```
Package zach Warning: Deprecated command \foo;
(zach)                \newfoo should be used instead
(zach)                 on input line 28.
```

whilst subsequent usages will not produce messages any more.

Comment: More or less what I was about to post but I have been too slow apparently :)